Intuition of time reversal Markov Chains
Just studying section 1.9 of Markov Chains by JR Norris. I noticed that most of the theorems are for invariant distributions. Why are time reversal Markov Chains defined for invariant distributions only? I do not know why but I think I am missing on some important intuition on time reversal Markov Chain.
Could someone please help me out?

The Markov property ("past and future are independent, given the present") is symmetric with respect to the direction of time.
If $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is a Markov chain with initial distribution $\mu$ and one-step transition matrix $P$, then for a given positive integer $N$, the time-reversed chain
$$
\hat X_n:=X_{N-n},\qquad n=0,1,2,\ldots,
$$
is again a Markov chain. The catch is that the transition probabilities for $(\hat X_n)_{0\le n\le N}$ need not be time-homogeneous. Indeed (assuming for simplicity that  probabilities appearing in the denominator below are $>0$),
$$
P[\hat X_{n+1} = k\mid\hat X_n=j] ={P(k,j)\cdot P^\mu[X_{N-n}=k]\over P^\mu[X_{N-n+1}=j]}.
$$
If the initial distribution happens to be the invariant distribution $\pi$, then $P^\mu[X_{N-n}=k]=P^\pi[X_{N-n}=k]=\pi(k)$, etc., and so
$$
P[\hat X_{n+1} = k\mid\hat X_n=j] ={P(k,j)\pi(k)\over \pi(j)},
$$
and the time-reversed chain is also time-homogeneous. (And conversely.)
